# FlowRouter, how to get data when routing depends on subscription

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, flow-router

I'm writing a licence validation part for my application and want to redirect the user to a renewal page if and only if their licence has expired.

I am using FlowRouter and Blaze.

All my authenticated routes are in a group:

```
let authenticated = FlowRouter.group({
  triggersEnter: [checkAuthenticated, checkSubscription]
});
```

I then check if the subscription is valid like so:

```
const checkSubscription = function(context){
  let path = FlowRouter.current().path;
  if (!Meteor.userId()){
    return;
  }
  const sub = new Subscription();
  if (sub.isInvalid() && path !=="/manage-practice/subscription"){
    FlowRouter.go("/manage-practice/subscription");
  }
};
```

My class subscription uses a collection that I can only load once a user has logged in. My problem is that the router usually triggers this redirection before this data has been loaded.

Is there a best practice approach to solve this?

Comment: are you using AccountsTemplates? i put together a solution w/ AccountsTemplates and alanning:roles that waits on roles before doing any routing. it's ugly, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

**Redirect with Triggers**

I'm not sure about this being 'best practice' but one approach is to use the Flow Router `redirect` functionality on your login event.

You can see examples at: https://atmospherejs.com/kadira/flow-router#redirecting-with-triggers and https://github.com/meteor-useraccounts/flow-routing.

The initial login path (using `Accounts.onLogin();`) could be to a generic 'loading...' template while you evaluate the user's collection.  On a callback you can then use the custom redirect function to either redirect to the requested page in your app, or redirect the user to your '/manage-practice/subscription' path.

**FlowRouter.wait()**

I have to confess I wasn't previously familiar with this second option, but I've just come across `FlowRouter.wait()`. This can be useful to delay the default routing process until some other evaluation is complete.  I suspect this might only be relevant if a user logs directly into a page within your `authenticated` routing group.

Documentation: https://atmospherejs.com/kadira/flow-router#flowrouter-wait-and-flowrouter-initialize

Comment: Hi David, I've looked at both those options before and you are spot on. `FlowRouter.wait()` is not suitable. I'm already using triggers, but my `Subscription` class used to require a load of the subscriptions to the practice of the user before it could evaluate if it was a legal subscriptions. Instead of a generic redirect page, I'm trying to use a server only method to get the practice outside of the subscription which is too slow to load.